# Cordova: After Angular 8 lazy load implementation, application does not start and after splash screen shows white screen

Tags: angular, cordova, lazy-loading

**Device:** 
 - Android and Simulator.

**Details:** 
 - Hybrid application using Cordova. 
 - Angular 8 lazy loading implemented in a Web application.

Scenario: After implementing lazy loading for web application and creating a Cordova 9.0 built for Android (.apk). The application installs and on opening shows splash screen but after that shows a white screen and hangs.

Error on debugging on emulator (same behavior in the real device
also): too much work on the main thread.

> **Question** : HOW CAN LAZY LOADING BE IMPLEMENTED IN CORDOVA WITHOUT
>   CRASHING THE APPLICATION?

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed the issue by adding "type=text/javascript" in index.html after creation of .dist file.

Because of angular differential loading runtime.js, polyfill.js gets added to indexl.html file and they have a TYPE=MODULE but "type=text/javascript" is not there (it would be helpful if it is included) hence web browser dose not have any issue identifying the MIME type but if we built an apk or ipa using the same .dist through cordova then Android native is not able to identify the MIME type hence the error is thrown.

Thanks.